# how can i export <img> tag in handsontable into .csv file as an image not html?

Tags: error-handling, export-to-csv, handsontable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIEkJ.png)
I want to export my handsontable as CSV file but its render as html. so when its downloaded it shows the HTML over there any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to export HTML tags into a CSV file, as they are not supported in this format.

Comment: So another file which similar excel file can do it? And which? Give me some recommends